# Cannot update TextView inside Observer.update

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem trying to `setText` of a `TextView` inside `Observer.update`. I tried to debug, and it did run into the update function, but the `setText` call was ignored.

```
if (step.getMyTimer().countObservers() == 0){
                Observer ob = new Observer() {
                    @Override
                    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
                        timerTextView.setText(step.getMyTimer().toString());

                        Log.v("INSIDE OBSERVER ", "");
                    }
                };

                step.getMyTimer().addObserver(ob);
                Log.v("ADD OBSERVER :", "");
            }
```

In the logcat, it did print out the `INSIDE OBSERVER`. 
Anybody have any ideas ?

---

So I tried to add this into `Observer.update` and timer :

```
Observer ob = new Observer() {
                    @Override
                    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {



                        Log.v("THREAD UPDATE OBSERVER ", ""+Looper.myLooper().getThread().getName());
                    }
                };

                step.getMyTimer().addObserver(ob);
                Log.v("THREAD ADD OBSERVER :", "" + Looper.myLooper().getThread().getName());
```

In timer :

```
_timer = new CountDownTimer(min * 60000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tick();
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
                clearChanged();
                Log.v("THREAD TIMER : ", "" + Looper.myLooper().getThread().getName());
            }
...
}
```

And this is output :

```
09-17 15:09:32.312    V/MAIN THREAD﹕ main--main
09-17 15:09:32.544    V/THREAD ADD OBSERVER :﹕ main
09-17 15:09:32.554    V/THREAD ADD OBSERVER :﹕ main
09-17 15:09:38.703    V/THREAD UPDATE OBSERVER﹕ main
09-17 15:09:38.703    V/THREAD TIMER :﹕ main
09-17 15:09:39.705    V/THREAD UPDATE OBSERVER﹕ main
09-17 15:09:39.705    V/THREAD TIMER :﹕ main
09-17 15:09:40.706    V/THREAD UPDATE OBSERVER﹕ main
09-17 15:09:40.706    V/THREAD TIMER :﹕ main
09-17 15:09:41.707    V/THREAD UPDATE OBSERVER﹕ main
09-17 15:09:41.707    V/THREAD TIMER :﹕ main
```

Comment: Try to log `step.getMyTimer().toString()` value and check what getting in log

Comment: The content of `step.getMyTimer().toString()` did change, but still cannot `setText`

Comment: How do you declare timerTextView and define the layout in the xml?

Comment: Its very normal. In fact, it did work before, when I declared a `CountDownTimer` inside the adapter and update the `TextView` each time the timer tick. However, this cause look like a whole mess, as I used another class similar to a Timer. So I decided to combine the real timer to my class, and use observer to update `TextView`, instead of doing it in timer's tick. And here comes the problem